# hdfs + file count on each recursive folder

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

we create the following bash script

this script will calculate the number of files under each HDFS folder

```
#!/bin/bash


hadoop dfs -lsr / 2>/dev/null| grep drwx |awk '{print $NF}'>/tmp/file

while read -r line 
do 
sleep 0.1
echo -n $line
su -l hdfs -c "hdfs fsck $line -files -blocks -locations -openforwrite 2>/dev/null| grep 'Total files'  "
done <  /tmp/file
```

Example of output

```
/applications Total files:  34198
/applications/hdfs Total files:     34185
/applications/hive Total files:     13
/apps Total files:      230
/apps/hive Total files: 443540
```

the problem with this script is the time that is needed to scan all HDFS and SUB HDFS folders ( recursive ) and finally print the files count

any other brilliant idea how to make the files count in HDFS much faster then my way ?

Comment: what you means - do you mean why I need the fast way?

Comment: if you want to know why I count the files on each folder , then its because the consuming of the name nodes services that are very high memory and we suspects its because the number of huge files under HDFS folders

Comment: ok, do you have some idea of a subdirectory that might be the spot where that is happening? Is it user home directories, or something in Hive? This will be easier if you can refine the hypothesis a little more.

Comment: no I cant tell you that , the example above , is only example and we have 100000 lines with folders

Comment: Why do you need to go through `fsck` file checking  in order to get a simple count? Can't you use a simple `hadoop fs -count`? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count

Comment: because I want to count the files of each hdfs folder